# How to pull all JSON data from a URL and store it?

Tags: javascript, json

For example, I have the following URL:

```
https://www.website.com/cf/script.php?page=1
```

This returns a large JSON object with 50 entries.  `?page=2` returns the next 50, so on and so forth.  What would be the best method to cycle through all given pages (say for example I want to go from pages 1-200) and store all the results in a separate table/database?  Preferable using Javascript.

Comment: So what have you tried already? The best method would be to write some code, see how it works and optionally improve, rinse, repeat. Then after you get stuck at the concrete problem - ask a question on SO with the code included.

Comment: I built a script in Google Sheets to import the JSON results, one page at a time.  It worked but I'm looking to automate it even more so I don't have to copy & paste 200 times.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to automate going through all pages or somehow remove the 50 result per page limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API documentation, as many APIs provide a way for you to specify the amount of entries in the response. E.g. limit=50, take=50. There is probably a maximum amount though.

There is also often other paging information in the response, i.e. how many more pages there are.
If that exists, you can create a loop that fetches each page, and creates/stores the results somewhere. Or you can just fetch and increment page until there are no more results.